# In SQL Server, how do I know what transaction mode I'm currently using?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, transactions

In SQL Server, how do I know what transaction mode I'm currently using? Such as ***autocommit, explicit, or implicit***. And how can I change one mode to another using tsql?
Great thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 PRINT 'No current transaction, autocommit mode (default)'
ELSE IF @@OPTIONS & 2 = 0 PRINT 'Implicit transactions is off, explicit transaction is currently running'
ELSE PRINT 'Implicit transactions is on, implicit or explicit transaction is currently running'
```

I don't think there is a way to determine whether current transaction was started explicitly or implicitly. So, this code just tries to guess: if IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is OFF, the transaction is assumed to be started explicitly.

MSDN references:

- [@@OPTIONS function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177525.aspx)
- [Numeric values for options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176031.aspx)
- [@@TRANCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187967.aspx)

Comment: I think that the message `No current transaction, autocommit mode (default)` is a little misleading since autocommit is not totally sure at this point, the connection could be set for implicit transactions but since no statement were issued yet, no transaction have been started.

Answer (score 7):

```
select @@OPTIONS & 2
```

if this returns 2, you're in implicit transaction mode. If it returns 0, you're in autocommit.

[BOL for @@OPTIONS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177525(SQL.90).aspx)

[BOL for what each option is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176031(SQL.90).aspx)

To switch which mode you're in, you'd use

```
set implicit_transactions on
```

or

```
set implicit_transactions off
```

Comment: It should be implicit_transactions.

Comment: @daniel_aren - true, changed now. Don't know why it wasn't spotted before.

Comment: Turning this ON/OFF does it happen at the Server level or the active session where the transaction is happening?

Comment: @SQLnbe - it's a connection level setting. See [implicit transactions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188317(v=sql.105).aspx): "When a **connection** is operating in implicit transaction mode ..." (my emhpasis)

Answer (score 6):

Slight modification to previously posted script - connection is in autocommit mode if there's no active transaction AND implicit transactions are off:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 AND (@@OPTIONS & 2 = 0)
  PRINT 'No current transaction, autocommit mode (default)'
ELSE IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 AND (@@OPTIONS & 2 = 2)
  PRINT 'Implicit transactions is on, no transaction started yet'
ELSE IF @@OPTIONS & 2 = 0 
  PRINT 'Implicit transactions is off, explicit transaction is currently running'
ELSE 
  PRINT 'Implicit transactions is on, implicit or explicit transaction is currently running' + CAST(@@OPTIONS & 2 AS VARCHAR(5))
```