# TSQL - Distributed or Local Transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, msdtc

I have some SPs in a "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3)" database.
These SPs might either be called from VB6 applications and other SPs, or from .Net applications.

If an SP is called from other SPs or VB6 applications I can rollback the current transaction and give proper error messages with `raiserror` in case of errors/invalid inputs.

But because connections opened by .Net applications are hooked to **distributed transactions** *if multiple WCF services are involved* (it is a company standard, we use MS DTC) I should not roll back the transaction and I should only call `raiserror` command.

If we roll back the distributed transactions, all error messages raised with `raiserror` command are lost and on the .Net side we get an exception whose message is:

> The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has
>   cancelled the distributed transaction

**How can I know if I'm in a distributed transaction or if I'm in a local transaction while coding within SPs?** If I'm in a distributed transaction, I will not execute the rollback statement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you, hopefully it's not too old http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919018/in-sql-server-how-do-i-know-what-transaction-mode-im-currently-using

Comment: Also, I don't know how many of these SPs you have, but you could have a parameter in each of them to indicate whether you should rollback or not

Comment: @MSANZ thank you, I've already visited this thread but it did not help about distributed transactions. It can only say none-implicit-explicit transaction modes. About adding a parameter to each SP, it's practically impossible because of the huge number of SPs and because SPs make subsquent calls to other SPs. I cannot know the path on which a transaction dismissing SP is called, so I have to add the parameter to all SPs and propagate the value to all subsequent calls too.

Comment: One other non elegant way is to detect which application started the session: SELECT client_interface_name FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions and react accordingly.

Comment: May those who voted down and voted for close can explain the why?

Comment: @Alex, I will try it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who faced the same problem, I've found a temporary solution:

I'm checking the `sys.dm_tran_session_transactions` view.

The column `is_enlisted` becomes true if I come from .Net and if I started a msdtc transaction in the .Net side.

Edit: the view `sys.dm_pdw_nodes_tran_session_transactions` is used in azure sql databases (this might be valid in clustered installations too, I think), and `sys.dm_tran_session_transactions` is used in other editions. So I edited the answer to use `sys.dm_tran_session_transactions`