# Data locks caused by non-committed transactions

Tags: sql-server

My web application is connected to a SQL Server 2016 Express database, and we have been plagued by data locks in certain areas of the system.

My colleague noticed just today that, when a KILL process was used to kill a long-running transaction, that several transactions that had ostensibly already been committed were rolled-back.

I have checked using @vladV's script on [In SQL Server, how do I know what transaction mode I'm currently using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919018/in-sql-server-how-do-i-know-what-transaction-mode-im-currently-using) that in fact the database seems to be in auto-commit mode.

So therefore it must be that that something in the database is opening a new transaction and not committing it.

So I found in the database four stored procedures which contain the following

```
SET  IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS  ON
... code ...
IF @@TRAN_COUNT>0 COMMIT WORK
```

Am I right in saying that in some/most situations such a stored procedure would leave transactions open, even after exiting the stored procedure, and that this could be the source of the data-lock problems?

And if so, then could I just remedy the code by doing

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
```

when the stored procedure exits?

Comment: Something that could help you out: [SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql). It looks like the answer to your questions is yes. Of course, you should test it to be certain.

Comment: If you are using SQL Express, your database is small and all queries should be very fast. Maybe it's better to optimize your long-running transactions to run faster.

Comment: @R. Richards - OK - thanks. I will try...

Comment: @MikhailLobanov - Agreed! But I think the reason in most cases that they are long-running is because of the data locks!

Comment: @gordon613 you can also try another transaction isolation levels (`SNAPSHOT` for example). Each isolation level have own number of locks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right in saying that in some/most situations such a stored procedure would leave transactions open

Some.  Depends on what comes after.  With IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS in SQL Server, transactions are not automatically started until you run a query that reads the database.

> could I just remedy the code by doing SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF

No.  That won't end any open transactions.

Note that COMMIT doesn't reduce the @@trancount to 0.  It decrements it by 1.  So if you have multiple BEGIN TRAN statements, or an explicit BEGIN TRAN after an transaction has implicitly begun, then you will need multiple COMMITs.

You might try

```
WHILE @@trancount > 0 COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

which will definitely commit any outstanding transactions.

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps it would be better if I was to replace SET IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS ON with BEGIN TRANSACTION and SET IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS OFF with COMMIT TRANSACTION. What do you think?

Comment: I prefer to _not_ to use IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS, and handle all transactions explicitly.  So that's a good direction, but it is more change.

Comment: OK. I will rewrite the stored procedures to use explicit transactions only.